# Controlling admission approval and unapproved status

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello guys I am making a college website project in MVC it has admission form so whenever a admission form is filled by user and gets submitted it goes for approval and the user receives his admission code to check the status of his/her account approval so I am having a problem here.

The Code:

**Model:**

```
  public partial class admission_tbl
{
    public int adm_id { get; set; } //- by this user checks his status//
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string std_name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string std_father { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string std_mother { get; set; }
    [AgeRangeValidation(ErrorMessage = "Age must be between 18 - 28", MinAge = 18, MaxAge = 28)]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string std_gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string R_address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string P_address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string adm_for { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string university { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string E_no { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Center { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Field { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Marks_secured { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string out_of { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Class_obtained { get; set; }

    public string Sports_details { get; set; }
    public string adm_status { get; set; } //--This is the method which i am using to control account 
                                                approval or non approval status.
           }}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Status_check()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Status_check(admission_tbl svm)
    {
        admission_tbl u = db.admission_tbl.Where(a => a.adm_id == svm.adm_id).SingleOrDefault();


        if (u.adm_status == "Approved")
        {
            ViewBag.Message1 = "Your account is Approved";
        }
        else if (u.adm_status == "Unapproved")
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your account is not Approved ";

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your account is in pending please wait";
        }

        return View();
    }
```

So, here in status check the user inputs his admission code to check whether account is approved or not everything works fine but the problem is when I try to input a random number input it throws null exception error instead I want to throw a message error for example "Invalid Admission Code no such exists" i couldn't catch it what am i missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yes I checked up on this still didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scenario that `svm.adm_id` is not existed in the records for `admission_tbl`

```
admission_tbl u = db.admission_tbl.SingleOrDefault(a => a.adm_id == svm.adm_id);
```

This `.SingleOrDefault()` will return NULL. Thus when you try to access `adm_status` from `u` which is null, you will get `NullReferenceException`.

To solve this issue, you need to add validation to check the `u` object cannot be null before proceeding to access its inner properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Status_check(admission_tbl svm)
{
    admission_tbl u = db.admission_tbl.Where(a => a.adm_id == svm.adm_id).SingleOrDefault();

    // Validate u cannot be null, if null do error handling
    if (u == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Admission Code no such exists";
        return View();
    }

    if (u.adm_status == "Approved")
    {
        ViewBag.Message1 = "Your account is Approved";
    }
    else if (u.adm_status == "Unapproved")
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your account is not Approved ";

    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your account is in pending please wait";
    }

    return View();
}
```

Note:
This statement

```
db.admission_tbl.Where(a => a.adm_id == svm.adm_id).SingleOrDefault();
```

can be replaced to:

```
db.admission_tbl.SingleOrDefault(a => a.adm_id == svm.adm_id);
```

Both will return same result and return null if the record is not found.

**Second Edit version:**
You can bind your error message in ViewBag, or add any handling for the scenario and immediately exit

```
ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Admission Code no such exists";
return View();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @yong but is it possible to throw just a error message on the same page instead of throwing exception?

Comment: Hi @Mac, yes sure, just replace the `throw new Exception()` with `ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Admission Code no such exists"`. I updated the code. You may refer it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is my answer ! Thanks again @yong